# GNU ddrescue - can someone give me a good command to run in terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, command-line-arguments, ddrescue

I have a damaged hard drive with many bad sectors from my parents windows computer, attached via Sata cable to a **Virtual** Ubuntu (on my Windows Desktop).
i want to use ddrescue (GNU) to create a Disk Image.
**Can someone tell me what to type into the ubuntu Terminal to achieve the following:**

- invoke ddrescue.
- skip over bad sectors (to avoid wasting hours and hours of time).
- create a Log (map file) to enable ddrescue to resume itself if the computer hangs or crashes or restarts.
- avoid imaging the Windows System Files (MBR) partition (as i dont intend to restore windows.. I only want to recover data and not waste time imaging windows OS files).

**Extra Questions** (to add to the above):

- Am I supposed to Un-Mount the damaged drive before invoking ddrescue ? how can I do this ?
- Will I be able to run ddrescue a 2nd time more thoroughly to try to image the sectors that were skipped on the 1st image and then MERGE these 2 images to create a more complete image ?
- Can I control how often the mapfile saves itself ?
- Can I control how many attempts it makes to read a sector before skipping to the next sector ?

**Software/hardware info**:
i'm running Ubuntu GNOME from a USB Memory Stick (virtual machine, and with Persistence on my Windows 7 Desktop computer).
Faulty Hard drive is connected to the motherboard with Sata Cable.

**PS**: Am I correct in doing this with Virtual Ubuntu ? or would I be better off installing ubuntu as a dual boot on my windows desktop ?
i am under the impression that the virtual machine Persistence setting will allow for the ddrescue mapfile to resume itself if the computer crashes or restarts.

Comment: whatver you do, do be careful, some jokingly call dd "destroy disk" because if you mix up the from and the to then you're screwed..

Comment: also I think you may have your understanding of technicalities wrong.. i'm pretty sure MBR is not a partition.. it has a partition table, and partion eitries, it describes partitions, but is not a partition. Windows 7 does have a special little 100MB partition for booting but Win XP doesn't, and Win XP could still have a partion table in the MBR form. As would Win98 and DOS, none of them had a special bootable partition.

Comment: thanks for the technical side.
but really I just want to know some examples of command lines

Comment: I have some examples but I have to go out now.  If I haven't replied by tomorrow night so within 24 hours then do an @barlop with a reminder.. I've sometimes used ddrescue from cygwin within windows, but the command is the same.  I don't know offhand if my examples will meet all of your criteria but many of your criteria are the kinds of things i'd look for so some might.

Answer (score 1):

You should check what disk is mounted where.. in the linux I used, and perhaps all linuxes, it's  $mount .  Recently used ubuntu and `sudo parted -ls` worked really well for showing partitions along with the make and model and capacity of a drive and the size of each partition.    You'd mount a partition of the target drive (the drive you will be writing the image to). Say it's sdb1, `sudo mkdir /mnt/whatever` and `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/whatever`. The mount command can autodetect the partition format/file system e.g. ntfs or whatever it is.

(i've used cygwin which doesn't use the moutn command, it's different and a little more complex to find that info in cygwin though you're not using cygwin)

You'll want to know what device /dev/sda is  what device /dev/sdb is e.t.c.

You shouldn't really have your file system like /mnt/whatever pointing to it(the drive you are getting the image from). Just like in windows you shouldn't really have a drive letter assigned to the drive. There's this idea that if it is then something could easily write to it when you don't want it to.

i'm really not an expert on this at all but I have managed it from cygwin, and  ubuntu

The basic command would look like this in cygwin

```
$ ddrescue -b 1M /dev/sdb /cygdrive/c/crp/asdf.a
```

or this in ubuntu

```
$ ddrescue -b 1M /dev/sdb /mnt/blah/asdf.a
```

essentially the same, just make sure you have the said 'to' directory so you can write the file there.

The command I used in cygwin (and I should probably have eliminated the -r3 at least the first time),  was `ddrescue -r3 -b 1M /dev/sdb /cygdrive/c/crp/fsfwr_.fc b.log`  You can add a log file as I have there. But I have found the output is quite brief anyway from ddrescue.  Some add --force / -f, i.e. `$ ddrescue -r3 -b 1M --force /cygdrive/c/crp/debian-live-7.6.0-i386-gnome-desktop.iso  /dev/sdb`  But that -f/--force just seems to mean overwrite the 'to' file if it already exists. So it's not really important 'cos you can delete the 'to' file yourself if you wanted to eg do ddrescue again.

I slightly doubt it will take hours or hours longer, with retries set to 3..

I've read that -r means retries and the default is 0, and best to eliminate the -r the first time. So, would be even faster..

some advice regarding -r, e.g. the commonly used -r3

https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/

```
-r3 tells ddrescue to retry bad sectors 3 times before giving up. Note: On a failing drive you may want to eliminate this option the first time so as to not waste time hammering on bad sectors and risking drive failure. You can always use the logfile to go back and retry the bad sectors after you get an image from the first sweep.
```

I've used -b 1M, this might be quite important, because the default is 512, and that would or could take ages.  dd had the same issue..  It's possible that you could do 4M maybe and 4M may be better, but the major difference is specifying 1M vs the default of 512 bytes.   I'm pretty sure i've done the default with dd of 512 bytes and it took ages.. and perhaps similarly with ddrescue. So do -b 1M at least.

Regarding -d I haven't really experimented with and without it.. it's to do with accessing the disk more directly. I've been ok with and without it, so I tend to do without it.

The 'from' goes first, and then the 'to' second so you shouldn't mix them up. But do double check.

And notice i've specified a log file.

Obviously it almost goes without saying that you can also check the manual for ddrescue

https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html

There is a version of ddrescue that isn't good. You want GNU ddrescue.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/211578/whats-the-difference-between-ddrescue-gddrescue-and-dd-rescue

You can used testdisk to read the file created by dd or ddrescue.